# Best Eclipse plugin for Maven 3

Tags: eclipse, maven

I've done some searching, but haven't found any satisfactory answers:
what's the best Maven 3 plugin to use with Eclipse?  Will the m2 plugin work satisfactorily?  I understand M3 tries to be backwards compatible where it can, but there are some differences.

Anyone's experience would be appreciated!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

A separate Maven plugin is no longer required. Maven 3 integration is built into the latest version of Eclipse (Indigo) by way of the m2eclipse plugin.

See the '[where is m2eclipse](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2011/06/where-is-m2eclipse/)' article for more information.

Comment: For those who want to know, Eclipse (Indigo) is version 3.7.

Comment: It seems you need at least Eclipse Luna to be able to install the m2eclipse plugin, as [indicated here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24479109/maven-for-eclipse-1-5-0-plugin-cannot-be-installed-under-kepler).