# Maven for Eclipse 1.5.0 plugin cannot be installed under Kepler

Tags: eclipse, maven, guava, m2e

I downloaded Eclipse Kepler and tried to install M2Eclipse from its [update site](http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases).

After selecting Maven Integration for Eclipse, I clicked Next and got the following error:

> Missing requirement: Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.5.0.20140606-0033 (org.eclipse.m2e.core 1.5.0.20140606-0033) requires 'bundle com.google.guava [14.0.1,16.0.0)' but it could not be found

So I searched through the internet to find out how to install the Guava Eclipse plugin. Some say it's from the Eclipse marketplace, but it cannot be downloaded. I downloaded the [binary](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/Release16) and tried to copy it to Eclipse's plugin directory. Still the same result.

```
cp ~/Downloads/guava-16.0.1.jar /Applications/eclipse/plugins/com.google.guava_16.0.1.v1234.jar
```

How do I install the m2e plugin for Kepler?

Comment: For those running Eclipse Indigo who get this error, you are out of luck:  http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/m2e-users/msg04751.html

Answer (score 83, accepted):

m2e 1.5.0 [requires Eclipse Luna](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/m2e-users/msg04751.html). It will not work with Kepler or Indigo. (thanks to [@HDave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218028/hdave) for the link)

So you have to use an older version of m2e under Kepler.

During installation, **uncheck "Show only the latest versions of available software"**. Then only check the 1.4.1 version or lower version in the candidate list. It doesn't require the Guava dependency.

Comment: `sudo eclipse` for installing / updating stuffs did the trick for me (my first attempt for installing 1.4.1 or 1.4.0 led to breaking most of my eclipse components...)

Comment: It's not actually true. Link by @HDave says that m2e 1.5.0 is incompatible with 3.7/Indigo. There is nothing about Kepler there. And actually, with guava installed from Orbit, I was able to update m2e on Kepler SR2 to 1.5.0.

Comment: This answer is incorrect, http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/release-notes-15.html states that m2e 1.5 is "compatible with both Eclipse Kepler and Luna"

Answer (score 25):

Make sure you have the Luna repository in "Available Software Sites".

You can add it in : Help -> Install New Software... 
Then in the "Work with" input, you type http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna/ and press enter.

After that, you should be able to install m2e with http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was looking for this from past 2 days. This worked for me like a charm!

Comment: That does not work for me, after installing all libraries from Luna, my Eclipse cannot be started. Loading Eclipse every time fails, I have to uninstall eclipse and reinstall everything again.

Comment: It works for me. You don't need to install nothing from the luna update site @Howy only add it to the work with list in order to m2 1.5 installation founds there what it needs

Comment: I was using Luna and getting the error described but putting in the first link you provided and selecting m2e 1.5 from there worked perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot. As Luna is still not running properly under Kubuntu (famous oxygen-gtk-bug), this helps a lot while still using Kepler and though being able to work with java 8 and what comes along.

Answer (score 9):

You can [find](http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20140525021250/) Guava 15 on [Orbit project](https://www.eclipse.org/orbit/) - "repository of bundled versions of third party libraries that are approved for use in one or more Eclipse projects". You can also directly add the [Orbit project update site](http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20140525021250/repository/) to your kepler installation and you'll be able to update m2e

Comment: Adding the Orbit project update site solved to me. Just added it and tried to install m2e from marketplace again and got no errors. I'm using Juno 4.2.2 . Thanks for this answer

Comment: Wow!  Fantastic find!  I just installed m2e 1.5 on Juno as well, and no installation errors.  It would be awesome if we could find somewhere else to add this (like a FAQ or something).

Answer (score 2):

What has helped me for Juno release is adding  http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.3/ as plugin update site. The version of  Maven for Eclipse was 1.3 instead of 1.5 but, for me, this differrence was less principal than the absence of extra dependencies and extra update sites, especially that of the newer version of IDE itself.

Do you necessarily need version 1.5 or 1.3 also should be good?

Comment: Thanks Michael. The mentioned URL can work properly.

Answer (score 2):

**STEPS TO INSTALL MAVEN (in Eclipse):**

Maven Eclipse plugin installation step by step:

> - Open Eclipse IDE
> - Click Help -> Install New Software...
> - Uncheck "Show only the latest versions of available software"
> - Click Add button at top right corner
> - At pop up: fill up Name as "M2Eclipse" and Location as"http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases"
> - Check only one 1.4.1 Version.
> - Now click OK After that installation would be started.

Answer (score 0):

http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases
This URL does not work.

http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.3/
This one can work.